# How does the doctrine of substantial forms differ from atomism?

Tags: epicurus, leibniz

Liebniz was an early admirer of Epicurean atomism; but later devoted himself to the doctrine of substantial forms as outlined in his *Monadology*.

On the face of it, atoms are substantial forms - they have substance and they have form; what are the major differences between these two theories?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you ask about the difference between an atom and a monad - is that right?

If it is, then the major difference between them is probably the fact, that a monad is not pure matter as atom (Epicureans were matterialists: even souls they considered to be build of atoms, just of some different type). I don't want to make a mistake, but I am quite confident that a substance in Christian philosophy is a term generally not associated with matter.

But there are other differences: I assume that Epicurus concept of atom is familiar to you and the Leibniz's monads just cause confusion. (Indeed, monadology is rather odd metaphysical system.) I would recommend those articles about monads, they describe the idea of a monad quite well:

http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Catholic_Encyclopedia_(1913)/Monad

http://www.iep.utm.edu/leib-met/#H4

Note the biggest differences:

- Atoms are pure matter, whereas monads are not.
- Atoms are connected with other atoms, whereas monads can not interact
  between them (monad "has no doors or windows")
- Atoms are what is the world build of in a sense as bricks are what a
  wall is build of, whereas monads are complete beings - they all are
  the parts of the universe and in every of them there is a
  *reflection* of the universe in which it appears as if they could interact.

And some differences according to particularly Epicurus' concept of atoms:

- Atoms are **not the smalles parts of the universe** - they are made of *minima*, whereas monads are indivisible.
- Atoms are not fully determined - there are some random movements of atoms called *clinamen* (greek: *parenklisis*), whereas monads... well, they are determined in a specific way and it is all quite complicated (the articles I recommended should put some light onto it).

---

On the other hand, there is no reason why couldn't the matter (*not* substance) be made of atoms in Leibniz's concept: I cannot though provide evidence that he has actually thought so and I am sure that it is not an important part of his philosophy (the atom concept in Epicurus' philosophy was developed for his ethics - and a similar role in Leibniz's philosophy certainly play monads).

Comment: Great answer; thanks for the references. You're right that I was asking about the differences between monads and atoms; is it correct to say in the Epicurean system that 'soul atoms' are made of matter, rather than being atoms of some spirit-like notion?  In a sense I see Leibnizs system as a spiritualised form of Epicures doctrine. Isn't the 'swerve' of atoms called *clinamen* rather than *parenklisis* - or are they the same concept in different languages? As I understand it, substances are defined as being causally closed - hence Leibnizs attempt to harmonise them through

Comment: his *harmonic* doctrine.

Comment: You are right, as I see *clinamen* is probably the most common name and it means the same as *parenklisis* - I didn't know the English word so just transcribed the greek word (google says that it is also used).

Could you elaborate how do you see Leibniz's system as a spiritualised form of Epicure's harmonic doctrine? I don't understand which exactly part of Epicure's philosophy you refer to (I may not be an expert of Epicure though).

Comment: There are similarities between monads and atoms - they are simple and indivisible is probably the key property; but whereas atoms are matter; monads are substances, thus able to support the notion of mind spirit in a way that is  different from Epicurus; also Epicurean atoms developed as a  reaction to Parmenides One - they are many; in the same way L's monads are Parmenides One multiplied. Epicurus didn't have a harmonic doctrine; it is Lebniezs; as each monad is causally closed how can they affect each other - they cannot; the harmonic doctrine is a way of getting around that...

Comment: I confess I find that confusing as what (sufficent) reason is there for them to harmonise.

Comment: "Leibniz answers by introducing the principle of Pre-established Harmony."
I must admit, that the metaphysics of Leibniz are neither my favourite, nor the simpliest. You can research the concept of Pre-established Harmony and maybe this'll do a little help, but honestly I also do not find it a good explanation.

What is important about the two discussed philosophers are the purposes of their physics/metaphysics: to E., the physics was to justify his ethics: the climenes for example is for making a space for free will...

Comment: L. is developing his metaphysics trying to reconcile modern physics with scholastic philosophy, theology and to complete his theodicy. As well as Epicur's physics is at some points self-contradictory, the monadology has in my opinion a lot of flaws and insufficent justifying. Personally, I think Leibniz is one of the best mathematicians and physicist and generally a brilliant person, but a poor philosopher.